# URL rewrite, cannot get page1/page2 path to work

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting

We're changing the design of an MVC .Net Core website.  Currently the vendor's name appears as a subdomain but we now need to use the subdomain for something else.  Two links that vendors need to continue to be able to send to customers are below, followed by the new URLs to which we want to redirect them:

1. http://vendorname.example.com => http://newsubdomain.example.com/vendors/vendorname
2. http://vendorname.example.com/signup => http://newsubdomain.example.com/vendors/signup/vendorname

It's hosted on an Azure app service so I'm editing the web.config directly on our test site.  I tried to use "Rewrite" as action type but had absolutely no success (constant internal site errors) so I've moved to using "Redirect" instead - although I'm concerned that as we will be removing the vendorname subdomains this may lead to problems when we move to live (doesn't a redirect require the original url to exist??).  For some reason the below only works for (1). I can't for the life of me get (2) to work even though it uses the same logic.

My questions in a nutshell:

- can I use "redirect" rather than "rewrite" if the original url doesn't exist any more?
- why does the first rule below work but not the second?

```
        <rewrite>  
            <rules>
              <rule name="1.Redirect subdomain">
                <match url="^http:\/\/(?!www)(\w+)\.example\.com\/?$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsubdomain.example.com/vendors/{R:1}" />
              </rule>
              <rule name="2. Redirect subdomain">
                <match url="^http:\/\/(?!www)(\w+)\.example\.com\/signup\/?$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsubdomain.example.com/vendors/signup/{R:1}" />
              </rule>
            </rules>  
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: I know that: For an HTTP URL in this form: http(s)://<host>:<port>/<path>?<querystring>
and: The <host> is available in the server variable HTTP_HOST and can be accessed by using a condition within a rule.
Take a look here and try to rewrite your rule:
[link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Comment: @smallweed Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the url rewrite's pattern is `The rule pattern is used to specify either the regular expression or a wildcard pattern that is used to match URL strings.`.

This part will just match the url pattern not the whole domain, if you want to match the domain, you should use url rewrite condition instead of pattern.

I suggest you could try to below rule to test if this rule match your requirement.

```
            <rule name="testrule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="signup(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="vendorname.example.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsubdomain.example.com/vendors/signup{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="testrule2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="vendorname.example.com" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsubdomain.example.com/vendors/vendorname/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]